# Send email when teamcity agent disconnects

Tags: teamcity

We are facing problems with third party drivers on our build machines that causes them to restart.
Is there a way to configure teamcity to send email when agent is disconnected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if TeamCity has this functionality built in. A solution could be to use the [REST API](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API) request...

```
GET http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/agents?includeDisconnected=false
```

... which will return an XML document containing the connected agents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<agents-ref>
    <agent href="/httpAuth/app/rest/agents/id:2" id="2" name="Agent2"/>
    <agent href="/httpAuth/app/rest/agents/id:3" id="3" name="Agent3"/>
    <agent href="/httpAuth/app/rest/agents/id:1" id="1" name="Agent1"/>
</agents-ref>
```

You could write an application in the language of your choice that polls this request, parses the XML document for the names of the connected agents, and then sends an email if the list has changed.